# Inserir "X" em célula futura

Tags: funções, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de inserir um X, como resultado de uma função, se possível. Ele deve aparecer N casas após uma soma retornar N.

Se A1=1 / B1=4 / C1=0 / D1=(Soma de A1+B1), que no caso seria 5.

Como fazer com que 5 células após C1 o retorno seja um "x".

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se já conseguiu uma solução para isso, mas tenho uma sugestão.
Existe um limite baixo para os possíveis resultados da soma de A1+B1?
Se sim, uma possível solução e usar a fórmula `=se($D$1=1;"X";"")` em cada uma das células à frente substituindo o número 1 após o igual pelo número referente a célula atual. Por exemplo, célula E1 fica com valor 1, célula F1 com valor 2, célula G1 com valor 3 e assim por diante. A célula que corresponder ao resultado da soma em D1 mostrará um X e as demais não.
Espero que isso ajude.